# Problema obtencion datos API

Tags: python, api

Estoy intentando hacer un PUT a una API para modificar unos datos y siempre me dá un error 400. Cuando intento realizar un GET no me da error y obtengo los datos por lo que la conexion la he descartado.
Cuando hago el siguiente curl me actualiza correctamente los datos.
`curl --request PUT -H "St2-Api-Key:*********" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://127.0.0.1/api/ --insecure --data '{"action": "update", "parameters": {"eid": "******", "url": "https://www**************/parameter/relevancia", "body": "\"0.77\""}}'`

Por lo que estoy seguro que debe de ser el formato que tengo yo en el código y que no consigo resolver.

`updateData("parameter", eid, "relevancia", '\"' + str(relevancia) + '\"')`

Por lo que necesito ayuda con el formato del body  `'\"' + str(relevancia) + '\"')`
Ahora mismo me llega el body de esta forma: `\"body\": \"\\\"94\\\"\".`
He probado varias cosas como quitar las comillas, añadir comillas simples, quitar el str y todo me da error.
Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias